# Apache: cannot rewrite sitemap.xml as sitemap.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, sitemap, web.sitemap

I have the following `.htaccess` file in the root (htdocs/johndoe) of my web document tree where `index.php` is found:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu1=$2&menu2=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu1=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule sitemap.xml sitemap.php
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but when I access:

```
http://localhost/johndoe/sitemap.xml
```

it just loads my `index.php` instead of calling `sitemap.php`. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule sitemap.xml sitemap.php
```

to the top of the `.htaccess` file just after the `RewriteEngine on` directive seemed to solve my problem.